# Why is variable value incorrect in callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is the `loading` variable in my `useInterval` callback function not correct? When the callback function is called, the `loading` variable in the function is always true even though the `loading` prop in `InfoPage` eventually is false. How would I fix this?

```
const InfoPage = ({ loading, fetchDataFn }) => {
  const [lastIntervalTs, setLastIntervalTs] = useState(new Date().valueOf())
  const [lastFetchTs, setLastFetchTs] = useState(new Date().valueOf())

  const refetchData = () => {
    const ts = new Date().valueOf()
    setLastFetchTs(ts)
    setLastIntervalTs(ts)

    fetchDataFn()
  }

  console.log('Outside callback', loading)

  useInterval(() => {
    console.log('Inside callback', loading)
    if (!loading) {
      setLastIntervalTs(new Date().valueOf())
    }
  }, 5000)

  const currentTs = new Date().valueOf()
  if (currentTs - lastFetchTs > 15000) {
    refetchData()
  }
}
```

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay = 0) => {
  const savedCallbackRef = useRef(callback)
  const intervalIdRef = useRef()

  useEffect((): void => {
    savedCallbackRef.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalIdRef.current && clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current)
    if (delay != null) {
      intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(savedCallbackRef.current, delay)
    }
    return () => intervalIdRef.current && clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current)
  }, [delay])
}
```

Console.log results

[image: Console.log results]

Comment: Is `if (currentTs - lastFetchTs > 15000)` supposed to be part of the component? It's currently outside of it.

Comment: @Unmitigated It's inside the component

Comment: Not with the current braces structure. Could you correct that?

Comment: Also, did you mean to put that check inside the `useInterval`?

Comment: Yep, I fixed it

Comment: So if you log the `loading` prop outside of your `useInterval()` in `InfoPage` and log it in the `useInterval()` callback the `useInterval()` shows `true` even though the outside log shows `false`? Your code seems like it should handle stale state/closures so it seems like it should be working to me. Perhaps the issue is in some other part? A runnable example would help us debug it more easily

Comment: Yes, I will edit my example to show what happens when I console.log the loading variable

Comment: The problem is this: `const savedCallbackRef = useRef(callback)`. How component renders work is that the function is called each time it is rendered. Therefoe the `loading` variable that you have in the beginning is a completely different one that what you have in the end. And you only process that one variable you got the first time the component is rendered.

Comment: Closure is exactly the problem here, or rather React is the problem. Old-school, plain, regular javascript programmers are familiar and are good at manipulating closures - which is what you're trying to do. React does not respect closures because it intentionally breaks closures by making each render of a component a separate scope. So React programmers will get confused by closures and javascript programmers are confused by React - until they finally understand what React is actually doing.

Comment: @slebetman Well the `useRef(callback)` is not the problem, it's part of the solution. But yeah, how to ref was used was a problem.

Comment: Btw, the `refetchData` call should definitely go inside a `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are evaluating `savedCallbackRef.current` only once when you start the interval, not every time when the timer fires. Apart from that, using a ref is the right approach to solve this.

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback)
  callbackRef.current = callback

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay == null) return
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
//                                 ^^^^^^^
      callbackRef.current()
    }, delay)
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [delay])
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? I thought passing in the function reference and passing an anonymous function is the same?

Comment: Only for a constant function reference. But the variable holding the function is changing here. It matters when `callbackRef.current` is accessed - it's either evaluated when you start the interval, or every time when the anonymous interval callback is executed.